# How to copy code from Notepadd ++ into a new file in vi editor?

Tags: linux, editor, notepad++, vi, redhat

I am creating a new file in vi editor that's gonna have the whole Jquery library code .. How can I copy the whole library from Notepad ++ to vi editor on my laptop ?  I'm creating this new file in vi that's gonna be called jquery-1.8.3.js , I just need to copy the whole code into that file from Notepad .. Thanks a bunch !!

Comment: Why don't you just open it in vi?

Comment: can yuo just copy the file from explorer and paste it - then open in vi?

Comment: Why are you creating the new file in vi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste from the clipboard into vi with one of the following:

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Sometimes you have to use *register +*, sometimes you have to use *register **.

For example: if you're using gVim or MacVim, you use **+**.

If you're using vim from a shell, you use *****.

---

As others have pointed out, it would be a lot easier to just open the file with vim!

Comment: My understanding has always been that the first of those options is best as it works on more platforms.

Comment: It's an "_either or_" scenario.  gVim and MacVim use the + register.  Vim from the command line on linux uses the * register.

Comment: ... or i (to insert) followed by SHIFT+INSERT (the insert key is next to the home/end/page up/page down keys.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file with Notepad++, load the file with vi.